# How to concatenate variables inside a ternary statement?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to do this:

```
name: {{ $value.enable | ternary $value.prefix $.Release.Namespace $value.suffix $value.override }}
```

But that syntax is wrong. I can't find any examples for how I would concatenate these vars together: `$value.prefix $.Release.Namespace $value.suffix`

### Edit

I thought I could use print like this:

```
name: {{ true | ternary (print $value.prefix $.Release.Namespace $value.suffix) $value.fullnameOverride }}
```

But if you don't specify one of the fields it prints `<nil>` instead of not printing anything which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm includes the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) template library which includes many useful composable parts.

For the "true" half, you have the three components; you'd like them joined together; but you'd like nil parts to be removed.  The Sprig `list` function constructs a list from arbitrary items; `compact` takes a list and returns a new list without empty items (either empty string or nil, anything that's a Go zero value); and then `join` combines the list together into a single string.  You can assign that to a temporary variable, and use it in the `ternary` call:

```
{{- $qualifiedName := list $value.prefix $.Release.Namespace $value.suffix | compact | join "" }}
name: {{ $value.enable | ternary $qualifiedName $value.fullnameOverride }}
```

I find the `ternary` syntax a little hard to read (even if it matches the C-style `expr ? t : f` syntax) and in this context it's not necessary.  A helper template that spelled this out could be easier to understand later.

```
{{-/* Generate the name of the thing.  Call with a list containing
      the top-level Helm object and an item from the values file.
      (Indented for readability, the template engine removes all of
      the whitespace.) */-}}
{{- define "name" -}}
  {{- $top := index . 0 -}}
  {{- $value := index . 1 -}}
  {{- if $value.enable -}}
    {{- with $value.prefix -}}{{- . -}}{{- end -}}
    {{- with $top.Release.Namespace -}}{{- . -}}{{- end -}}
    {{- with $value.suffix -}}{{- . -}}{{- end -}}
  {{- else -}}
    {{- $value.fullnameOverride -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

name: {{ include "name" (list $ .) }}
```

Comment: kinda stinks this is what you have to resort to, to use the ternary operator with variables like this. I just used an IF/ELSE instead. The whole point of a ternary operator is supposed to be a terse and readable one liner- defining a var using 3 different functions(!) to process it first is the opposite of this

Comment: "Concatenate three variables, but suppress nulls" isn't easy in many languages.  You don't _have_ to assign it to a variable, but `$condition | ternary (list $a $b $c | compact | join "") "otherwise"` is a lot to fit into a single template expression block.